# Node.js profiler exits after Express server starts

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm using `sudo node --prof server.js` to try and profile an Express server. However, as soon as the server starts, the profiler quits. I'm not able to send any requests during that time. How do I make the profiler stay active so I can send a few requests?

Comment: If you check https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/simple-profiling/ it says a tick file was generated in the same directory as your local run of the application when using the --prof. Or you can also run the application using command sudo node --inspect server.js

Comment: The tick file is there, but it's only for the startup of the server. The server should stay running until I can send it some requests to profile. Since the server exits before it can receive any requests, the tick file is useless.

Comment: @LeoJiang Without profiler your server is working properly?

Comment: Yep, the server runs continuously without the `--prof` argument.